# Angular js Asocciative array ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays

i have an angular js array binded to the $scope object. The array is an associative array. Simple array of arrays, and i dont know how to traverse through it in ng-repeat. This is my array, and I want to get the path of each file which on 0th index in sub arrays. I want to get

**files/file/img1.bmp**, 
**files/file1/img1.jpg**,
**files/file2/img1.jpg**

```js
$scope.im = [

 ["files/file/img1.bmp", "files/file/img2.jpg", "files/file/img3.jpg", "files/file/img4.jpg", "files/file/img5.jpg", "files/file/img6.jpg", "files/file/img7.jpg", "files/file/img8.jpg", "files/file/img9.jpg"],
 
 ["files/file1/img1.jpg", "files/file1/img2.jpg", "files/file1/img3.jpg", "files/file1/img4.jpg", "files/file1/img5.jpg", "files/file1/img6.jpg", "files/file1/img7.jpg", "files/file1/img8.jpg", "files/file1/img9.jpg"],
 
 ["files/file2/img1.jpg", "files/file2/img2.jpg", "files/file2/img3.jpg", "files/file2/img4.jpg", "files/file2/img5.jpg", "files/file2/img6.jpg", "files/file2/img7.jpg", "files/file2/img8.jpg", "files/file2/img9.jpg"]
            
];
```

Comment: this is not associative array. Its nested(2D) array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an associative array cause you got no key for your values.

However, given your code if you want to iterate over your array just use :

```
<div ng-repeat="file in im"> 
    <!-- Now file is your list (e.g. ["files/file/img1.bmp", "files/file/img2.jpg"] -->
    <p>{{file[0]}}</p>
    <p>{{file[1]}}</p>
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

And you will get the first element of each one of your items in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! is there any solution for how can I parse that sub array now , I am using JSON.parse($scope.im[i]); but thats showing me error, the "im" array is parsed, but the sub arrays are treated as a string in my case, i want to parse those sub arrays

Comment: You re welcome . You cannot parse your sub array with json cause they are not. What output do you want ?

Comment: Basically i am facing a problem, I have taken multiple files from HTML input. When the submit button is clicked , a dynamic array of those files paths has been made , and then I JSON encode that array, which is dynamically made, and insert it in a database table. Till the database insertion it is fine, but the problem occurs when i retrieve that array, using angular js ajax, that array is treated as a string, then I make it JSON.parse to convert it into array, so the $scope.im is basically that array which contains the parsed array, but the sub arrays are still treated as strings

Comment: the need to parse those sub arrays too is,  I am making html elements dynamically, they are populated with respect to the response from the ajax call, as much records i have in the database that much elements are made, but here in each element there is an image place, where i want to put the very first image on each element from the sub arrays. like on first element i want to put image from sub array 1 0th element files/file/img1.jpg, on second element i want to put image from sub array 2 0th element files/file1/img1.jpg and so on...

Comment: And all the time, i faced failure; What i did now, when i am making array during  execution time, i save the first image in a separate column, and then retrieve that column value, but still, when i JSON parse that value, on each elements same img has been shown, not the relevant ones, which i want.

Comment: I see, the best option here is to make another question to prevent spamming this one. Use some console.log to debug and show us the errors and logs you got. (Link us the question here pls)

Comment: Sure , let me make it

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44256593/angular-js-ajax-and-php-data-parsing-errors) is the question, please review

Answer (score 2):

Displaying image out of those nested array could be simple, here is an example:

```
<div ng-repeat="childArray in im">
  <div ng-repeat="photos in childArray">
      <img src="{{items}}" alt="something" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. As @Priyesh Kumar commented so you should use nested `ng-repeat`

```
  <div ng-repeat="key in im"> 
     <div ng-repeat="value in key"> 
        {{value}}
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array, `im`, normally as described in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and access the first element of your inner array

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="list in im">
       <!--- list now represents the inner array --->
       {{ list[0] }} <!-- write the first path -->
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work for each index of the sub arrays:

```
<div ng-repeat="(idx, value) in im[0]"> 
    <br>
    <div ng-repeat="file in im"> 
        <p>{{file[idx]}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would print :

files/file/img1.bmp
files/file1/img1.jpg
files/file2/img1.jpg

files/file/img2.jpg
files/file1/img2.jpg
files/file2/img2.jpg

...