# Angular JS ajax and php data parsing errors

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays, http

Basically I am facing a problem, I have taken multiple files from HTML input. When the submit button is clicked , a dynamic array of those files paths has been made , and then I JSON encode that array, which is dynamically made, and insert it in a database table. Till the database insertion it is fine, but the problem occurs when i retrieve that array, using angular js http calls, that array is treated as a string, then I make it JSON.parse to convert it into array, so the $scope.im is basically that array which contains the parsed array.

Now,I am making html elements dynamically, they are populated with respect to the response from the ajax call, as much records i have in the database that much elements are made, but here in each element there is an image place, where i want to put the very first image on each element from the sub arrays. like on first element i want to put image from sub array 1 0th element files/file/img1.jpg, on second element i want to put image from sub array 2 0th element files/file1/img1.jpg and so on...

these are the elements made dynamically, the transparent one the image section.
[image]

This is how I parse the array.

```js
$http({
     method:"POST",
     url:"files.php",
     data:$.param({
            tot_data:true
     }),
     headers:headers
    }).then(function(res){
     $scope.d = res.data;
        $scope.im=[];

       for(var i=0; i<$scope.d.length; i++){
       $scope.im = JSON.parse($scope.d[i].imgs);
          console.log($scope.im[i]);
       }

    });
```

**This is the result I get on console:** 
[image: And all the time, I faced failure]

**But when I put it in the html**

```js
<p>{{im[0]}}</p>
```

**Still I get the same path on each element, not as the result shown on console**
[image]

Comment: What is the ouput if you print `{{im}}`

Comment: ["files/file3/img1.jpg","files/file3/img2.jpg","files/file3/img3.jpg","files/file3/img4.jpg"]       **this array on each elements**

Answer (score 0):

Managed to iterate over your array with the following code

**JS**

```
    $scope.test = ["files/file3/img1.jpg","files/file3/img2.jpg","files/file3/‌​img3.jpg","files/fil‌​e3/img4.jpg"];
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="t in test">
     <div>
          <b>{{t}}</b>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Output :

[image: output]

With this you should be able to display all your images. (integrate the ng-repeat in whatever element you want).

Basically if your take the code from your following question you could have something like

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="files in im"> 
    <<ul>
      <li ng-repeat="f in files">
         <div>
               <img ng-src="{{f}}" alt="Your wonderful image" />
         </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.im = [

 ["files/file/img1.bmp", "files/file/img2.jpg", "files/file/img3.jpg", "files/file/img4.jpg", "files/file/img5.jpg", "files/file/img6.jpg", "files/file/img7.jpg", "files/file/img8.jpg", "files/file/img9.jpg"],

 ["files/file1/img1.jpg", "files/file1/img2.jpg", "files/file1/img3.jpg", "files/file1/img4.jpg", "files/file1/img5.jpg", "files/file1/img6.jpg", "files/file1/img7.jpg", "files/file1/img8.jpg", "files/file1/img9.jpg"],

 ["files/file2/img1.jpg", "files/file2/img2.jpg", "files/file2/img3.jpg", "files/file2/img4.jpg", "files/file2/img5.jpg", "files/file2/img6.jpg", "files/file2/img7.jpg", "files/file2/img8.jpg", "files/file2/img9.jpg"]

];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The code you wrote is correct, but if you re read my question, the sub arrays need to be JSON parsed, because the sub arrays are treated as strings, and i can't JSON parse them , if you have any solution to parse those sub arrays then it will be helpful

Comment: var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray); Should do the work